# How to do scale to fit in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a feature that when a user clicks an image, a div will pop and animate from the size of the image to fit the entire browser window.

It will be something like

```
 -----------------
|                 |
|      img1       |
|          img2   |
 -----------------
```

After click `ima2`

```
 -----------------
|                 |
| image2 contents |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

when `img2` is clicked, the div that has contents will pop and animate to fit the entire browser viewable screen. I am thinking using css transform to do this but I am not sure how to start and how to lock the image contents position. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you wanting a modal window to pop up? Or did you want the page layout to change?

Comment: page layout won't change, just a new div popup and cover the originally loaded page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/AcG2Y/)?

JS

```
var $dialogpopup = $( ".hiddenimagediv" ).dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 'auto',
                  width: 'auto',
                  position: {my: "top middle",
                             at: "top middle",
                             of: ".imagediv"},
                  title:"Your Picture"});

$('.imagediv').click(function(){
                               $dialogpopup.dialog('open');
                               });
```

You can remove the upper bar, play with the formatting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zoom images on your page, I have recently built a script that handles this pretty well:

https://github.com/kthornbloom/Smoothzoom

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Nivo Lightbox in the past, and it's quite simple to set up. It basically is just a popup on your page that shows an image, gallery, or even video overtop of the content (with an overlay).
http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-lightbox/

I know this is just one of the many other lightboxes out there, but this one worked great for me.